# powerpoint- Define new numbering: No such menu item

Tags: numbering, list, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I'm trying to change numbers' font of a numbered list. Stories tell that there should be a "Define new numbering" item in Numbering menu in Home tab of ribbon which I can use to define a new numbering style, but there isn't such a thing there. Only "Bullets and Numbering" is there. Environment: Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 6.1.7601, PowerPoint 2016 MSO 16.0.8730.2165. Please help.

[Numbering Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhruF.png)

Answer (score 0):

> > ... there should be a "Define new numbering" item in Numbering menu in Home tab of ribbon ...

This is true for Word, but PowerPoint doesn't offer the same option.